# Where is my dynamic control after I submit the form?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, code-behind

I created a dynamic form with a repeater.

```
<asp:repeater ID="fieldRepeater" OnItemDataBound="dataBound" runat="server">
    <itemtemplate>
        <div id="controlRow" class="row" runat="server">
            <div id="testContainer" class="col-md-2" runat="server">

            </div>
        </div>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

in codebehind I created the field I want to appear in it.

```
Protected Sub dataBound(ByVal sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    dim temp as new DropDownList
    dim tempLabel as new label
    Dim testContainer As HtmlGenericControl = e.Item.FindControl("testContainer")

    'createField
    temp.ID = "testField" & e.Item.ItemIndex 'this is testField0
    temp.Items.Add(New ListItem("Not Used", 0))
    temp.Items.Add(New ListItem("Used", 1))
    temp.CssClass = "form-control"


    'createLabel
    tempLabel.ID = "testFieldLabel" & e.Item.ItemIndex
    tempLabel.AssociatedControlID = "testField" & e.Item.ItemIndex
    tempLabel.Text = dr("controlLabel")
    testContainer.Controls.Add(temp)
    testContainer.Controls.Add(tempLabel)
end sub
```

The form works beautifully and I can even pre-populate it with data from a db, but in my submit handler my controls don't exist:

```
Protected Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
    Dim i As Int32 = 0
    For Each r As DataRow ...
        'db stuff
        Dim temp As New DropDownList
        temp = Me.FindControl("testField" & i.ToString)
        'db stuff            
        i += 1
    next
end sub
```

`temp = Me.FindControl("testField" & i.ToString)` is always `nothing` Can someone help me find out why?

My HTML output looks like:

```
<div id="cntMain_fieldRepeater_testContainer_0" class="col-md-2">
    <label for="cntMain_fieldRepeater_testField0_0" id="cntMain_fieldRepeater_testFieldLabel0_0" style="color:#007AFF;">Activity</label>
    <select name="ctl00$cntMain$fieldRepeater$ctl00$testField0" id="cntMain_fieldRepeater_testField0_0" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Not Used</option>
        <option value="1">Used</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically created Controls need to be (re)created on every Page Load, and that includes a PostBack. So you have to move the DataBinding of the Repeater outside the `!IsPostBack` check.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    fieldRepeater.DataSource = loadDataHere
    fieldRepeater.DataBind
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each item As RepeaterItem In fieldRepeater.Items
        Dim temp As DropDownList = CType(item.FindControl(("testField" + i.ToString)),DropDownList)
        temp.BackColor = Color.Red
        i = (i + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I was almost there (Kinda)! I had gotten it down to `fieldRepeater.item(i).findControl("testField"&i)` thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. But you could also put the Controls directly in the `itemtemplate`. That way you won't need to recreate them dynamically.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but because the elements are in a Repeater you won't really have to. They are assigned a unique name and id. And you can access them exactly the same in `Button1_Click`: `Dim temp As DropDownList = CType(item.FindControl(("DropDownList1")),DropDownList)`

Comment: PS if my VB looks a bit strange, I use a code translator from C# > VB

Comment: I keep forgetting I don't have to micromanage form fields like that. 10 years in cold fusion having to build the field from the ground up, it isn't much different from asp classic and abusing the request scope. I'll rewrite it like you suggested. Thanks again

Comment: after adding the controls to the itemtemplate I had to place the repeater binding inside a`!IsPpostBack` block or the data inserted was the default value of the blank form.